# Drilling down (combination, via facets) on a Multivalued Solr field

Tags: solr, facet, multivalue

I'm looking to drill down on a multivalued field that contains (space) delimited list of words; but still returning facets at each step of the drill-down.

**Example Table**
ID, Properties (multivalued field)
1, "Yellow Green Square"
2, "Yellow Round Purple"
3, "Yellow Purple"
4, "Green" - *Doesn't really matter, just showing there are properties that don't contain Yellow*.

I am able to drill down on the first *property* ("Yellow"), and have the the following properties return, via facet:
Yellow (3) - *Omitted From Display; but returned regardless*
Purple (2)
Green (1)
Round (1)
Square (1)

And the following results returned: **1, 2, 3**

So what I expect is that if I apply the second *property* ("Purple"), I get the following:
Purple (2) - *Omitted From Display; but returned regardless*
Yellow (2) - *Omitted From Display; but returned regardless*
Round (1)

And the following results returned: **2, 3**

The issue we're running into is that once the 2nd facet property is applied, we get the results we are expecting; but all the facets disappear (even ones outside of the *property* facet).

I'd like to be able to drill down to a single record; which in this case would to apply "Round", and getting record ID 2.

Any help would be greatly appreciate; the documentation solr hasn't really helped (nor have any of the books).

Comment: (space) is a bit of a weird one in solr. any chance you can separate with e.g. dash (-)? then you could query e.g "fieldName:*-purple*" to get all facets with 2nd level purple

Comment: No facets are returned after 2 property facets are applied (the raw url, running Zend Framework is: http://www.example.com/search/index/property/Yellow/property/Purple). The url is set up to translate duplicate keys into an array.

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Multi-Select_Faceting_and_LocalParams